# return full row from oracle sys_refcursor function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have this function:

```
create function get_next_unlocked_id
  return varchar2
is
  cRefCursor sys_refcursor;
  rRecord    MESSAGES%rowtype;
begin
  -- open cursor. No locks so far
  open cRefCursor for 'Select s.guid,
       s.message_id,
       s.status,
       ...
       s.last_answer_date,
       s.response_message_id
from messages s,
     providers bp,
     groups bg
where status = ''SENT''
  and s.real_bsp_guid = bp.guid
  and bp.bsp_group_id = bg.guid
  and bg.guid = ''123''
order by insert_date for
  update of s.GUID skip locked';

  -- we fetch and lock at the same time one record
  fetch cRefCursor into rRecord;

  -- close cursor
  close cRefCursor;

  -- return ID or any other attribute(s)
  return rRecord.GUID;

end;
```

And it work. But I need return `full row` instead only `GUID`. Table has many colums. Should I list them all (~ 30) or how can I make it easier?

Comment: Why are you using a ref cursor for this? And why the dynamic SQL statement?

Comment: In this case, you sholud use cursor loop. Anyway, you have to list all columns

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're trying to invent queuing - have you considered using Oracle's [Advanced Queues (AQ)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/toc.htm)? That should save you some trouble, once you've set up the queue(s).

Comment: @fuNcti0n you don't have to list all columns; you can return a record...

Comment: @Boneist Yes, I'm trying to invent a queue. such an approach was advised to me on the SO. ` Advanced Queues` I have not studied yet

Comment: @ip696 If you're wanting to use queues in the database, I would highly recommend you don't reinvent the wheel yourself, and instead go with Oracle's queuing implementation. IIRC, you need to set up a table to hold the queue rows, a queue, you need to turn the queue on and give privileges, and then it's simply a matter of enqueuing and dequeuing messages to add to/pull from the queue. It's been a while since I last used them, but they're not that complicated to use, and setting them up isn't that arduous.

Comment: @Boneist not everything is so simple) Besides, I do not want to transfer a lot of logic to the base

Comment: @ip696 if you'd rather re-invent the wheel, by all means go ahead. But writing your own code to do something the database can do out of the box seems a bit daft to me. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @ Boneist Code of my application works with oracle and postgreSQL. And you do not know the complete logic of the problem. I appreciate your advice, and will definitely return to this option. But at the moment I asked a question and am waiting for help in solving this particular issue.